# icinga nrpe executes locally instead of server

Tags: nagios, nrpe, icinga

I am very new to icinga. In fact I finished setting it up today.

I am trying to monitor a bunch of stuff on my nrpe machines. I set up my services in `/etc/icinga/objects/my.server.com.cfg` and configured it like so:

```
define host{
        use                     generic-host   
        host_name               my.server.com
        alias                   my.server.com
        address                 123.45.678.999
        }

define service{
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       my.server.com
        service_description             Total Processes
        check_command                   check_procs!250!400
        }
```

When looking in the admin interface I was wondering why all servers are having the same amount of processes active, but after checking the command icinga executes, I realized that all commands are being executes on the icinga server itself rather than the nrpe machine.

Where is my mistake? `nrpe.cfg` is set up correctly to whitelist my icinga server. Telnet connection works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://wiki.icinga.org/display/howtos/Setting+up+NRPE+with+Icinga has the details, but you need to set up a proxy command. Something similar to:

```
define command {
    command_name check_nrpe_command
    command_line $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$ -a $ARG2$
}
```

Once you have that, you can set up your remote commands:

```
define service {
     [stuff]
     check_command check_nrpe_command!check_procs!250!400
     [more stuff]
 }
```

What it does is builds a local check that calls the local NRPE checker to query the remote system.

Comment: I found that there is a ubuntu package which adds a check_nrpe command, which seems to do exactly the same thing. But while this is working, the argument array is not getting created correctly. The third passed argument, $ARG3$, simply gets ignored instead of appending to the -a list, resulting in a lot of undefined commands. Thoughts?

Comment: Forget a commend. I took some time to debug and see how icinga / nagios passes / parses arguments and figured to just replace the `!` after check_nrpe with spaces for argument separation. (Since it's getting passed through -a). NRPE working now